# How to get all starred projects by a user from the Gitlab API

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I want to get a list of all projects that a certain user on Gitlab has starred using the Gitlab API and Python (via python-gitlab).

The documentation from python-gitlab on [users](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/users.html) does not mention starred projects. It may be a user activity, but the documentation on user activities just refers to user activity managers and about [that no further documentation](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/gitlab.v4.html#gitlab.v4.objects.UserActivitiesManager) is available.

With the Github API and pyGithub it's possible to achieve that using

```
import github
g = github.Github()
u = g.get_user()
u.get_starred()
```

However, with the Gitlab APi and python-gitlab I only get as far as:

```
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab()
u = gl.users.get()
u.get_starred()  # AttributeError
u.starred()  # AttributeError
```

I think it might be possible because on a Gitlab website I can see the starred projects of a user. Example: https://gitlab.com/users/username/starred

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `gitlab` python package has it. But there is a REST API for the same. Refer this link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-projects-starred-by-a-user

You can use `requests` module to do the GET and POST requests using python.

Comment: It may not be part of the Gitlab Python package, because [a search on their repository](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/search?q=starred_projects) for "starred_projects" did not give anything.

Comment: I see. Then go ahead and try the REST API if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that and maybe also open a feature request with them.